# JQuery Sortable "Out" Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I have two HTML unordered lists that I am using as a shopping cart in conjunction with jQuery draggable and sortable as demonstrated on their website demos.

We have a requirement that if a user drags an item outside of the selected items of the shopping cart, it is supposed to be removed.

We also are using MVC 5 and Ajax to update the shopping cart for every completed action... if an item is dragged into the selected items, it is added to a database table or cache immediately.  If an item is sorted in the selected items list, we capture the old index and new index and update the precedence value on the backend immediately.  These two features are working fine.

The issue I have is that according to the documentation (https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-out) and proven through Inspect Element is that the "Out" event for jQuery sortable might fire on two different occasions:

1. if a sortable item is dragged outside of its container.
2. if the sortable item is dropped.

Correct me if I am wrong, but the second time that the out event fires doesn't make sense to me.  The "out" event will fire also if, let's say the user starts to move an item, but then doesn't move an item and releases the mouse.

How do you accurately determine if a sortable item has been dragged and dropped outside of its container list (not moved within its container)?

Comment: if it is easy for you to create a jsfiddle, please do it.

Comment: [`receive:`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) "This event is triggered when an item from a connected sortable list has been dropped into another list. The latter is the event target."

Comment: Or, you could set a parameter on `sortstart` like "ogParent" and on `sortstop` check if the new sortable parent is equal to the "ogParent" using `.isSameNode()` like [this](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/KKMoxKM)

Answer (score -1):

Our solution was to forego using JQuery UI for sorting and drag/drop operations.

We used sortable.js which seemed to be a lot clearer as to handling sorting and drag/drop events.